# "The system cannot find the path specified" when I first start Command Prompt

Tags: path, windows-10, environment-variables

Something is wrong with either my user or system path variable, I think. But I'm having a hard time diagnosing it.

When I start Windows Command Prompt, I get this message:

"The system cannot find the path specified" when I first start Command Prompt"

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have invalid paths in your PATH environment variable.

Try 'echo %PATH%' and looking at the directories listed.

More information here:

https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/01/the-system-cannot-find-path-specified-error-in-command-prompt.html#axzz75wV3rIqY